# Is Logan no longer the Wolverine?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, x-men-apocalypse, x-men-origins-wolverine

Logan in 1973 (*X-men Days of Future Past*) managed to set a new future for himself and for everyone else, which suggests that he may well have never had the chance to meet the real Stryker (again)...

There's also the possibility that Stryker didn't find his special "meteor fragment" in order to produce adamantium to inject in Logan's bones.

[image: Logan holding not really dead Kayla]

If so, Logan probably didn't have the chance to meet his girlfriend Kayla (*X-men Origins: Wolverine*) who told him about the sad story of Kuekuatsu (or Cuckoocachoo, as Logan promptly understood and identified later as *the Wolverine*)...

[image: Logan without a clue of what's going on]

Therefore, how likely is Logan to become the Wolverine after 1973?

P.S.: Concerning **X-men: Apocalypse**

> I haven't seen this movie yet, but I'd like to understand if Logan is the Wolverine in it. If he is, is the movie inserted in the older continuity?

Comment: You do remember that in Wolverine 2009 movie adamantium was completely sucked out of his body? Then again in "Days of Future Past" starting scene (future) he had them back. It was probably Magneto who helped out with that, as we know from the first X-men trilogy, Magneto can control adamantium despite that it is "indestructible". While Charles probably worked on Logan's mind during of after the procedure, prevented pain and lose of memories or smtn like that. And you do remember the ending scene (future) from "Day of Future Past"? He woke up back in school, so.. https://youtu.be/YdCb-nhLeYY

Comment: X-men was never made to weave together like the way Marvel movies does....it's only after Marvel started doing things, then X-men went "Oh, we can do that too". You will only have to accept it the way it is, without trying to dive too in.....I still can't figure how Xaviers came back from dead,...I know in comics a lot of characters have came back from dead....but in the movies, they just don't want to explicitly explain how Xaviers came back and how Magneto got his powers back.

Comment: Such movies were also never made to make sense, full of plot holes and logic errors, but the meaning of this site is to work together to figure it out, call us the debuggers. Ha ha. Anyway, Speaking of how Charles came back from dead, it's just another hilarious thing, X-Men The last stand had a post-credit scene you obviously haven't seen. https://youtu.be/LnVoTt35Uw0 It seems that Charles had a brain-dead twin Brother who was kept alive on life support system all those years for some reason. And guess what, He's also paralyzed. Refer http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Charles_Xavier_(Earth-10005)

Comment: @Lettmannen, you say as if Wolverine lost his memories because of the adamantium operation he got through, but this is not true.
Wolverine lost his memories after the operation when his girlfriend died and someone blew his brains out with adamantium bullets. (which in turn could go through his adamantium skull)

Comment: Noted. My mistake, it's been a while since saw those movies, no surprise one could forget some parts.

Comment: @MaartenOlijve There are inconsistencies between the movies, even if you ignore the fact that Days of Future Past altered the timeline. Origins is especially bad for this.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to answer it without giving spoiler so I am avoiding use of spoiler markup. 
So here it goes :

**Is Logan no longer the Wolverine?**

If by Wolverine you mean Weapon X/Metal claws then you are wrong, he do have metal claws and been through Weapon X program and real Stryker was involved.

[image]

Even his look in the film was quite similar to his comics counterpart of Weapon X

[image]

But how did Logan come into possession of Stryker is unknown. In X-Men: Apocalypse, Jean Grey and team released Logan from the chamber where Stryker's people kept him. He had metal claws and seems to have memory issues too but Jean helped him and gave some of his memory back but we don't know exactly what happens to him between DoFP and X-men Apocalypse. Maybe we can know more details in sequels. Maybe in [Untitled Wolverine sequel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Untitled_Wolverine_film) or some other X-men sequel.

Comment: I took the assist in releasing Logan from Weapon X to have been what had always happened in order to result in his getting free in the first place, Logan just doesn't know it.  Jean only seemed to manage to let him get the name "Logan" at the point he was escaping; given the mental turmoil he was suffering it's entirely possible that running into Jean/Scott etc for a few seconds was lost amongst the maelstrom in his head which was focussed on escape at the time.